# chrome disable security messed chrome functioning

Tags: google-chrome

[google image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkivV.png)

Hi, stackoverflow, i am trying to debug a react native app on a Mac and when i open chrome in disabled security mode, the data rendered by google chrome is not normal.
google resultas are not shown, and the design of chrome get messed (the image above)

this is the command : open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using Chrome 67.
This problem has been fixed in the last Canary, so you can:

1. wait for the next Chrome
2. use an old version (e.g. install Chromium 66)
3. or you can:

> Add the `--disable-site-isolation-trials` argument to chrome via https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Usage
>
> Reference: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951#issuecomment-401579981